# Buttons moving after textField is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm working on a login screen where you first choose whether you want to sign up through email, FB or Twitter. If you choose email, the buttons slide out of the screen, and the email login, with email text field, password text field and login button slide in the screen. I use this code:

```
@IBAction func emailLoginButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.facebookButton.center = CGPointMake(self.facebookButton.center.x - 500, self.facebookButton.center.y)
        self.twitterButton.center = CGPointMake(self.twitterButton.center.x - 500, self.twitterButton.center.y)
        self.emailButton.center = CGPointMake(self.emailButton.center.x - 500, self.emailButton.center.y)
        self.emailTextField.center = CGPointMake(self.emailTextField.center.x - 500, self.emailTextField.center.y)
        self.passwordTextField.center = CGPointMake(self.passwordTextField.center.x - 500, self.passwordTextField.center.y)
        self.loginButton.center = CGPointMake(self.loginButton.center.x - 500, self.loginButton.center.y)

    })

}
```

This works perfectly: when the email login is chosen, everything slides left, and you can enter your email and password. However, as soon as I click in the email text field or the password text field, everything instantly comes back into place. Weirdly, if at this point I choose email login again, it still works and everything slides left. But overtime I click a text field, everything comes back as if I had just launched the app.

Any idea? I'm thinking it might have to do with UITextFieldDelegate doing something upon detecting clicks, but I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using auto layout you can't directly edit the frames of your views, you need to move them by editing the constraints.

Comment: I'm not using auto-layout, I just positioned them in storyboard but added no constraints at any level.

Comment: Did you turn auto-layout off for the storyboard? Or did you leave it on and just not add constraints?

Comment: I don't know how to check that but I assume it is on since I use it for other view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.emailTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.passwordTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.emailButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.facebookButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.twitterButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

to your view controller's viewDidLoad

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode tells me this code is incorrect, the only thing approaching it is translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints() but it doesn't change anything to my problem.

Comment: If you're using swift 1.0 you should update but in the mean time use setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true) instead.

Comment: If you need more information, you can read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints